# How to align Facebook and Tweet buttons?

Tags: html, css, facebook, twitter, vertical-alignment

The Facebook and Tweet buttons on our home page are vertically misaligned, and we're confused why. We can top align the two buttons if we use Firebug and remove the height for the Tweet button. However, the height is set dynamically, and inlined, from a Twitter script. We can't seem to override the height value.

Here's the home page: http://www.panabee.com

Are we doing something wrong in the CSS? Or is there a parameter we need to set in the Tweet button to override the height value?

Our only other option is to resort to the Twitter iFrame for the Tweet button, which we prefer not to do.

Thanks!

Comment: I've met the same problem.. Here's what i've found.

[Answer here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770372/misalignment-of-facebook-twitter-buttons

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add:

`height:63px;` to the class of the FB iFrame in CSS:
[image]

Comment: thanks, myles! is there a method where we don't need to hard code the value -- to future proof the case where Twitter changes the height?

Comment: also, any feedback on the site?

Comment: @Crashalot The problem wasn't twitter it was FB, And it wasn't the size of the button that was the problem it was just an inherited style so nothing to worry about :) + Site looks really cool - Im usually quite good coming up with random names for sites but this is bookmarked!

Comment: gotcha, thanks @myles! do i need to worry about hard coding the value for the FB iFrame in case FB changes the height in the future?

Comment: @Crashalot nope - there is room for expansion in there, but FB wont change it - think of all the sites they'd mess up...

Comment: thanks, @myles. so i understand the problem and can diagnose similar issues in the future, can you explain what the problem was exactly? thanks again!

Comment: @Crashalot Yep sure the iframe for some reason was inheriting a style that was causing the height to be 107px for some reason, in future just use Firebug to diagnose such things :)

Comment: thanks, @myles. we used firebug, but we didn't notice the inherited style. thanks again ... lastly, would you mind FB liking the site and/or tweeting about it? just trying to spread the word. no worries if you prefer not to. thanks again! :)

Answer (score 25):

Simply add this CSS: `.twitter-share-button { vertical-align:top }`.

Comment: thanks, @thirtydot. but i awarded the question to @myles since he did provide a pixel perfect response. btw, any feedback on the site? thanks again!

Comment: @Crashalot: No problem, I agree. Regarding feedback, nothing particular comes to mind - it looks fine to me.

Comment: thanks, @thirtydot! would you mind FB liking the site and/or tweeting about it? just trying to spread the word. no worries if you don't consider the site useful enough. thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

To solve the default style

```
    <span style="vertical-align: bottom">
```

can be fixed by seting

```
    .fb-like {
        line-height: 0.7
    }
```

or

```
    .fb-like span {
        position: relative;
        top: -7px
    }
```

in your CSS