# Facebook and Twitter official buttons: over-ride CSS to display inline and float right?

Tags: css, twitter, facebook-like

I'm trying to use the official Facebook and Twitter buttons together.

I'd like to float them both right, inline with a third button, so that all three are arranged neatly and on one line, in the top right-hand corner of the UI.

I'd like the ordering as follows: Twitter button, Facebook button, third element.

This is proving surprisingly difficult, despite quite a lot of StackOverflow [hunting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252323/how-to-align-facebook-and-tweet-buttons) and Googling. I've set up a JSFiddle here to show the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/KHRJU/4/

How can I over-ride the CSS styles so that all three elements are in the top right-hand corner of the HTML display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KHRJU/6/)
I guess you'll understand :)

Comment: As I understood you wanted something like this?

Comment: That is perfect - thank you so much. Hope this is helpful for others with the same question.

Comment: Didn't You miss a closing div? http://jsfiddle.net/KHRJU/91/ Anyway You are the best!