# Facebook like modal hidden below the page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

When the like button gets clicked on our page the share modal gets hidden below the page in Chrome.

It shows the errors: "Unsafe Javascript attempt to access frame with URL" but I don't think this is related because I've seen the same errors on other sites and it still works for them.

[image]

Our site runs over HTTPS (not sure if this matters) and the the code is pretty much a direct copy paste from Facebook:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/Coinbase" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="85" data-show-faces="false"></div>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=154072648063392";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you provided enough info, but the general solution to this type of problem is to move the like button up in the page.

update: add clearfix to the container of the like element.

Comment: That would be one solution, but there is some other problem happening because this works on other webpages.  heyzap.com and kippt.com are both examples where it works correctly (and they aren't using any additional javascript from what I can tell to adjust the page).

Comment: Ok, I see. You want the page to expand down. Your question was extremely vague. I went to heyzap.com and noticed their footer container (which houses the like button) uses **clearfix**. Apply a clearfix solution to your page and it might work. I say might because you provided almost no info about your page so it's hard to know exactly what's going on.

Comment: Thanks, your clearfix idea led me down the right path.  I simply removed the like button from a table td element, and put it back in a div.  And it started working.  Had to apply this CSS to get it lined back up with the tweet button: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5252384/76486 Thanks!